# Cron Jobs and Background Tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am studying about **Cron Jobs** and **Background Tasks** in Ruby On Rails. Can anyone tell me which one to use as currently I am using Whenever Gem. Why `whenever` is better than `Sidekiq`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not comparable entities. As you are studying I will use few simple examples.

`whenever` is a cron job manager. In simple words it is alarm clock for task execution. Usually you can clean your server tmp nightly with such task.

`sidekiq` is a background job manager. You can use it to asynchronously process heavy load tasks on demand.

P.S. You cannot replace whenever with sidekiq without changing in approach for task execution and there should one better suitable, not "better, because sidekiq".

Answer (score 1):

`whenever` will generate a cron configuration for you. This is abstracted via the use of a Ruby DSL. This is not necessarily easier, but it may be if you are more familiar with Ruby than with cron. In particular it allows you to schedule jobs to run at specific intervals. These jobs typically run asynchronously and separately from the main ruby web application.

`sidekiq` provides you with the interface to run asynchronous background tasks. It does not schedule them to run at specific times, as might cron, without further modules i.e. `sidekiq-cron` or `sidekiq-scheduler`